# rubygems upgrade syntax errors

Tags: rubygems

I'm trying to upgrade rubygems to 1.8.11 and I'm getting tons of warnings and syntax errors ; I tried to upgrade to multiple versions like 1.8.6, 1.8.7 but nothing worked.

Can anyone please help me to identify what am I doing wrong?

```
[root@localhost rubygems-1.8.11]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.18-274.3.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Sep 6 20:14:03 EDT 2011 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux

[root@localhost rubygems-1.8.11]# pwd

/home/tac/rubygems-1.8.11

[root@localhost rubygems-1.8.11]# ruby -v

ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [i386-linux]

[root@localhost rubygems-1.8.11]# ruby setup.rb

./lib/rubygems.rb:332: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version

./lib/rubygems.rb:514: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version

./lib/rubygems.rb:30:in `require': ./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:54: syntax error (SyntaxError)
        define_method name do |*args, &block| # TODO: really works on 1.8.7?
                                     ^

./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:55: syntax error

./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:64: syntax error

./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:69: syntax error    from ./lib/rubygems.rb:30
        from setup.rb:27:in `require'
        from setup.rb:27
[root@localhost rubygems-1.8.11]#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to upgrade ruby or use an older version of rubygems.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by upgrading Ruby version

```
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

Thanks all for your help